# Ajax.beginform when submitting it creates more than one entry in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax.beginform in create form when I submit the form it create more than 1 entry in database first time it create 3 entries the second submit 6 rows and so on ..

Here is my index view :

```
@model IEnumerable<CourseSelection.Models.country>
@{
    Layout = Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null :  "~/Views/Shared/parameterview.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
<script src="~/js/main/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<div class="btn-danger ma ci" style="height:50px ;">
    <h2 class="white" style=" float:left; margin-left:5px ; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:10px;"> COUNTRIES </h2>
    <button id="sh" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right; margin-right:5px;">
        @Ajax.ActionLink(
            "Create",
            "Create",
            "countries",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "EditDivId",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith

            })
    </button>
</div>



 <div id="EditDivId">
 </div>
<div id="indexdiv">
<div class="nicdark_space10"></div>
@{ Html.RenderAction("_i");  }

</div>
```

here is my create view :

```
@model CourseSelection.Models.country

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "countries", FormMethod.Post, new            AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "indexdiv",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith


}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div id="tt">
    <div class="nicdark_bg_blue blueb" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="addres">Country Name</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="countryName"     class="form-control add" id="countryName" name="countryName" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="active">Passive</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="true" id="active" name="active" style="width:34px" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="active" />
                </div>

            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label for="s"></label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="s" style="margin-top:6px; width:80px; height:35px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label for="hi"></label>
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger" id="hi" style="margin-top:6px; margin-left:3px; width:80px; height:35px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

}
```

and here is my controller :

```
public class countriesController : Controller
{
    private CourseSelectionEntities3 db = new CourseSelectionEntities3();

    // GET: countries
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.countries.ToList());
    }

    public PartialViewResult _i()
    {
        return PartialView("_i", db.countries.ToList());
    }

    // GET: countries/Create
    public PartialViewResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_c");
    }

    // POST: countries/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,countryName,active")] country country)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            country.countryName = country.countryName.ToUpper();
            db.countries.Add(country);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("Index", db.countries.ToList());
        }

        return PartialView(country);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks It is working finally , really big thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")` more than one. Remove script parts from your create partial view and even from your other view if those scripts has been rendered in your layout page (master page).

**Important Note:**

if those scripts has been rendered in your layout page (master page) then you don't need those scripts anywhere else.

**Description:**

Here is a part of code that will run when you put jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your page:

```
$(function(){
    //...
    $(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
        var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [],
            clickTarget = $(this).data(data_target),
            isCancel = clickTarget && clickTarget.hasClass("cancel");
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (!isCancel && !validate(this)) {
            return;
        }
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method || "GET",
            data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
        });
    });
    //...
});
```

So every time you render that file, this event handler will attach to your submit button.